# drupal 7 - getting webform submissions that falls between 2 date

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

**webform_get_submissions()** in Drupal 7  return all the Webform submissions, the problem is that I want to return the submission that falls **between 2 date**

ex:
get webform submissions that have been submitted between 16 April 2018 and 28 April 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share a workaround that I came up with, maybe it will help you to find a full-size solution.

You actually can use a filter in the function `webform_get_submissions` not only by `nid` or `sid` but apparently by any other field. In this case, there is possible to use a filter by a field named `submitted`:

```
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid' => $node->nid, "submitted" => "1503753434"));
```

It will result in recieiving a submission which field `submitted` is exactly equal to `1503753434`. To get all submissions which are, for example, newer than `1503753434` one way is inside a file `includes/webform.submissions.inc` for the function `webform_get_submissions_query` change this part:

```
foreach ($filters as $column => $value) {
  $pager_query->condition($column, $value);
}
```

to this part:

```
foreach ($filters as $column => $value) {
  if ($column == "submitted") {
    $pager_query->condition($column, $value, ">");
  } else {
    $pager_query->condition($column, $value);
  }
}
```

This would result in getting submissions which are newer than `1503753434`. By analogy we can add `<` filter or any other filters.

The problem with this workaround is that it requires to change a source file of Drupal and also it requires implementing a simple parsing by hand in case we want to have several conditions for one field name.